# Use 2D matrix as indexes for a 3D matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say I have an array of shape 2x3x3, which is a 3D matrix. I also have a 2D matrix of shape 3x3 that I would like to use as indices for the 3D matrix along the first axis. Example is below.

Example run:

```
>>> np.random.randint(0,2,(3,3)) # index
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])

>> np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,3)) # 3D matrix
array([[[4, 4, 5],
        [2, 6, 7],
        [2, 6, 2]],

       [[4, 0, 0],
        [2, 7, 4],
        [4, 4, 0]]])
>>> np.array([[4,0,5],[2,6,4],[4,6,2]]) # result
array([[4, 0, 5],
       [2, 6, 4],
       [4, 6, 2]])
```

Comment: How does the shape of 2D array relate to that of 3D one?

Comment: It has the same 2D shape, but is only 2D. So the 3D array has the same shape NxN as the 2D array, but has more "layers".

Comment: Are your 2 different matrices repeated numbers like the example? Otherwise, you would need to give more information about how you want the output to look. For example, what do the 0's and 1's mean to you?

Comment: This is currently too broad. Please clarify more about what the output is doing, I can think of at least three different methods to use those three 2D arrays to get that result

Comment: @MatthewMage Use random numbers than those repeated numbers. That is bound to confuse people.

Comment: The 0's and the 1's represent indices the retrieve a value from the "layer" of the 3D matrix.

Comment: @Divakar Is there an easy way to use MathJax here?

Comment: Try : for 2D - `np.random.randint(0,2,(3,3))` and for 3D - `np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,3))`. And then you could show us the expected output.

Comment: Are you essentially just "masking" the first array of 1's using the array of 0's and 1's with the replacement mask as the second?

Comment: @MatthewMage you would need the column,row, and T you want... a "0" could be the first row and column of the first T, but what do the other 0's mean?

Comment: Input: http://i.imgur.com/X8H6K6N.png
Output: http://i.imgur.com/kQjcLCI.png

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Yes, in a way. Doing a "composite" of multiple layers.

Comment: @MatthewMage Don't post screenshots. Those can't be copied and run. Do something like `Sample run` from my post and show us the expected output. Feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: In this particular case, you can use np.where

Comment: @MatthewMage If it's worth the trouble, for the index array, you can use : `np.random.randint(0,4,(3,3))` and `np.random.randint(11,99,(4,3,3))` for the values array, for the benefit of the readers. Just to clarify on people assuming that you only have 0s and 1s in the index array.

Comment: @Divakar I added some clarification and removed those images. Sorry about that, I'm quite new to SO. Let me know if anything else should be changed.

Comment: @MatthewMage As I said `np.random.randint(0,4,(3,3))` for index array and `np.random.randint(11,99,(4,3,3))` for values array/3D matrix alongwith the expected output would be the best thing for future readers. I guess, it's okay, because it seems your problem has been solved.

Comment: @MatthewMage Took the liberty to edit the text on shape info to match up with the sample data. Hope that looks okay.

Comment: @Divakar yes, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you are using `2D` array as index array and `3D` array to select values. Thus, you could use NumPy's [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
# a : 2D array of indices, b : 3D array from where values are to be picked up
m,n = a.shape
I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
out = b[a, I, J] # or b[a, np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n)]
```

If you meant to use `a` to index into the last axis instead, just move `a` there : `b[I, J, a]`.

Sample run -

```
>>> np.random.seed(1234)
>>> a = np.random.randint(0,2,(3,3))
>>> b = np.random.randint(11,99,(2,3,3))
>>> a  # Index array
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
>>> b  # values array
array([[[60, 34, 37],
        [41, 54, 41],
        [37, 69, 80]],

       [[91, 84, 58],
        [61, 87, 48],
        [45, 49, 78]]])
>>> m,n = a.shape
>>> I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
>>> out = b[a, I, J]
>>> out
array([[91, 84, 37],
       [61, 54, 41],
       [37, 49, 78]])
```

Answer (score 4):

If your matrices get much bigger than 3x3, to the point that memory involved in `np.ogrid` is an issue, and if your indexes remain binary, you could also do:

```
np.where(a, b[1], b[0])
```

But other than that corner case (or if you like code golfing one-liners) the other answer is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

There is a numpy function off-the-shelf: [np.choose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).
It also comes with some handy broadcast options.

```
import numpy as np    
cube = np.arange(18).reshape((2,3,3))
sel = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0,1,0]])

the_selection = np.choose(sel, cube)


>>>the_selection
array([[ 9,  1, 11],
       [ 3, 13, 14],
       [ 6, 16,  8]])
```

This method works with any 3D array.

Comment: Can you edit your code to work with the shape mismatch? This method does not work based on the OP's problem.

Comment: In case someone else finds this post, np.choose works perfectly fine for OP's problem, as here illustrated with a range, rather than a random 3D array for clarity. However, in the case of a binary 2D array, and a two-layered 3D array, Daniel F' s smart answer using np.where is faster.

Comment: No it does not work and what range are you talking about? The OP has a variable with shape (2,3,3). If you try to run your code with a non-cube it breaks.

Comment: I've updated the answer to generate a 3D array with the exact dimensions as OP, this works as well. np.arange generates a range of values, so that you can see for yourself from which layer the value is selected. OP's title suggests that he is interested in a general case, but uses an example of a 3D array with first axis=2 ('Say I have an array of shape 2x3x3'').

Comment: This is the best answer. I'm not sure of the performance of choose versus ogrid, but the cleanliness is unbeatable